# Specified cast is not valid in linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, casting, datatable

Is there some way rather than try and error to specify which field makes the problem and what's the correct field type ?

I get the following exception :

> Specified cast is not valid.

```
 var vacStatiscs = from x in dtGivenBal.AsEnumerable()
                                  join y in dtTakenBal.AsEnumerable()
                                  on x["emp_num"].ToString() equals y["emp_num"].ToString()
                                  into joined
                                  from j in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      emp_num = x.Field<int>("emp_num"),
                                      name = x.Field<string>("name"),
                                      startBal = x.Field<int>("startBal"),
                                      prevMon = x.Field<int>("PrevMon"),
                                      added = x.Field<int>("Added"),
                                      taken = (j == null) ? 0 : j.Field<Int32>("sum")

                                  };
```

---

Now if I remove `startBal ,prevMon ,added`, I get no exceptions.

**Note:** the previous fields are result of `COUNT` and `SUM` SQL queries

Comment: Could any of these fields be null?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no direct way to detect which field makes the problem.

To answer your second question how to find out the correct field types:

```
Type fieldType = dtGivenBal.Columns["startBal"].DataType;
```

So you can use the [`DataTable.Columns`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.columns(v=vs.110).aspx) collection to determine the type of each column(f.e. via debugger). On this way you will also find out the wrong types.

Comment: Thank u so much ,u save my time :)